# Can a non-virtual function be equal to 0?

Tags: c++, virtual

Can a non-virtual function be equal to 0, e.g., something like

```
void foo() = 0
```

where the keyword `virtual` is not in front?

Comment: A function cannot be equal to anything, it's not data. The `= 0` notation after a fumction declaration denotes something else. No, this notation cannot be used on non-virtual functions. Yes, it can be used on virtual functions even if the word `virtual` is not present.

Comment: [No](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/LH5znw95CdcVnqBy). What would that even mean?

Comment: @n.m.: Thank you. How can a function be virtual when the word "virtual" is not present?

Comment: A member function that overrides a virtual funcction in the base class is automatically virtual even if the virtual keywors is not used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

When applied to a virtual function, `= 0` makes it pure virtual. It means nothing on a non-virtual function.

Update: A virtual function does not necessarily begin with the `virtual` keyword, in cases where the function overrides a virtual function in its base class.

Answer (score 8):

It is not a function being equal to zero, it is a designator of a pure virtual function.

Knowing that, it's clear that non-virtual functions cannot be designated pure virtual.

However, if s base class has a virtual function that your class is overriding, you don't need to repeat the virtual designator, yet you are allowed to mark the function pure virtual.

Comment: best answer here...if you override then it is legal

Answer (score 5):

`= 0` does not mean that the function is null. It is just a syntax for telling compiler that this is pure virtual function. You can't have pure non virtual function, because it will be impossible to instantiate such class and it will be impossible to override the function in child classes. But the code you've shown may appear in a program is `foo()` is declared as virtual in parent class.

Answer (score 2):

`virtual` marks a function virtual and `= 0` marks it pure virtual *in addition*.  A non-virtual, pure function... what would that be?

So no, that doesn't work.